# How many p-th power modulo $p^{2}$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

'p' is an odd prime, p $>$ 11 and let $ m = p^{2} $.

I was wondering if we have knowledge about how many elements in $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ are a p-th power i.e. what is the cardinality of the following set:

$\{x^{p} : x \in\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \}$

Comment: Note:  $(x+p)^p\equiv x^p \bmod p^2$

Comment: $(\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z)^\times$ is cyclic of order $p(p-1)$ when $m=p^2$; why restrict to $p>11$?

Comment: OP has not specified that he’s looking in $(\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z)^\times$ only.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thank you very much.. I got red-faced embarassed that I asked such an easy question, as soon as I saw your hint..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if $p\mid a?$

Else $(a,p)=1$

let $g$ is a primitive root

and if $a_k\equiv g^{m_k}\pmod{p^2},0\le m_k<\phi(p^2)$

If $a_i^p\equiv a_j^p$

$g^{p(m_i-m_j)}\equiv1$

$p(p-1)$ must divide $p(m_i-m_j)$

$\iff p-1$ must divide $m_i-m_j$

Clearly there can be $p-1$ in-congruent values of $k$ namely $1,2,\cdots,p-1$

Comment: The set $\{x^p:x\in\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z\}$ also includes $0$, so its cardinality would be $p$, right?

Comment: @Tanner, yes I have chosen co-primes of $p^2$

Comment: incongruent is one word not two.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee, incongruent  is not accepted as correct

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Aincongruent&oq=define%3Aincongruent&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.10399j1j7&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8